# How to handle static assets with AWS Amplify and Next.js?

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I'm working on a Next.js project hosted on AWS Amplify, and I'm wondering what the best way is to handle static assets (images, fonts, css, js etc.) with this setup.

I've seen two potential solutions:

1. Using remotePatterns in the next.config.js file to target a CDN.
2. Using AWS Amplify's built-in storage solutions for static assets.

Which of these solutions is the best practice for a Next.js app on AWS Amplify?
Are there any performance or cost considerations that I should be aware of?

I'm currently using option #1. I have implemented the remotePatterns feature in my next.config.js file, defined a CLOUDFRONT_URL constant in a separate constants.ts file, and I'm using that constant to reference the static assets in the Image component.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your usage, do you have any idea of what traffic you are expecting? With Amplify you can get free 12 months free and then you will have to pay the cost for the build, storage, data transfer and SSR requests and SSR request processing. With CloudFront and S3 option you will pay for S3 storage, and data transfer out to Internet and Origin. With CloudFront, the first 1TB per month of data transfer out to the internet and 10 million http/https requests from all edge locations except china are free. If you have good caching you will be able to reduce costs of data transfer to Origin.